# Calculate Difference In Volume Using Specific Volume

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, work, volume

I am calculating the work done in expansion from water to ice.

The pressure and temperature is constant (1 atm / 0 Celsius).

I am given:

- The initial volume (water) as 2x2x2 cm.
- Density of water is 1 g/cm3
- Density of ice is 0.915 g/cm3

From the initial volume and density of water, I determine the substance weighs 8 grams (none of it evaporates).

My question is, by by inverting the density of the water and ice (1/0.915 - 1/1) to find specific volume, can I then multiply the result by 8 grams to find delta V?

I apologize in advance, I haven't done physical science problems in a few years.

Comment: Work done by what on what?

Comment: Work done in expansion by water freezing.  This means the work is done by the system on itself?  It's actually not really relevant to the question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's definitely one way to do it.
If you're ever in doubt it's always best to work out the equation using variables and then substitute in your values later. You can verify that your equation will give the change in volume

since $v = \frac{V}{m}$ where v is the specific volume, m the mass, and V the volume. Then

m($v_{ice}-v_{water}$)

$mv_{ice}-mv_{water}$

$V_{ice}-V_{water}$

So it does indeed give you the difference between the volumes of the ice and water.